# Adding hyperlinks to notes in Mermaid Sequence Diagrams

Tags: hyperlink, href, sequence-diagram, mermaid

I've looked through the [mermaid sequence diagram](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram) docs and found how to add links to actors in a sequence diagram, but I'm interested in adding links to a note.

I found that `<br>` is supported in notes but other tags are not. Is this possible?

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant Alice
    participant John
    links Alice: {"Dashboard": "https://dashboard.contoso.com/alice", "Wiki": "https://wiki.contoso.com/alice"}
    links John: {"Dashboard": "https://dashboard.contoso.com/john", "Wiki": "https://wiki.contoso.com/john"}
    Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
    John-->>Alice: Great!
    Alice-)John: See you later!
    Note over Alice, John: I want to<br>be a link
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may relate to your question: Try this chart below - if you click it, you will be redirected to Google.

[image]

**The trick here is to combine the image and link functions in markdown.**

```
[![](https://mermaid.ink/img/pako:eNo1j8EKwjAQRH9l3avtD-RQETyo4MlrLksytYU00TRBSum_m7a4p2F4w87MbIIFKx7xyfAGl15eUQbtqdzZ9QZ10xzvofOKrnAu0Kor6sKXJIKmkE87vPp1gestpehGLeDoFSHpwBUPiIP0tvya14Dm1GGAZlWkRSvZJc3aLwWVnMJz8oZVihkV57eV9K_GqhU3Fhe2TyE-9v7bjOUHTYdELA?type=png)](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNo1j8EKwjAQRH9l3avtD-RQETyo4MlrLksytYU00TRBSum_m7a4p2F4w87MbIIFKx7xyfAGl15eUQbtqdzZ9QZ10xzvofOKrnAu0Kor6sKXJIKmkE87vPp1gestpehGLeDoFSHpwBUPiIP0tvya14Dm1GGAZlWkRSvZJc3aLwWVnMJz8oZVihkV57eV9K_GqhU3Fhe2TyE-9v7bjOUHTYdELA)
```

While it is possible to add link (*I have read about it in the mermaid.js book and will get back to you in the near future*), but depends on the format of the output (*.png, etc*) you may lost this function after rendering. The only format that makes it possible is html. As:

> Possible Values You Can Set securityLevel to: … loose: Mermaid will
> allow HTML tags in text. The interactivity in the diagrams provides
> support for **click events**.
> Page 83, *The Official Guide to Mermaid.js* by Kunt Sveidqvist & Ashish Jain